# c++ linker error - 'undefined reference' to not inline defined functions

Tags: c++, linker, g++, codeblocks

For few days I'm trying to compile one project written in C++ using Code::Blocks IDE (on Linux, Ubuntu 64-bit). Code is valid but there are some linker errors. I noticed that I get errors 'undefined reference' for functions which are not inline defined in classes and are in other files (class is i *.h file and definitions on these functions are in *.cpp). I tried to write my own Makefile but it didn't help.

Makefile:

```
all: project

project: main.o DList.o Person.o
    g++ main.o DList.o Person.o -o project

main.o: main.cpp
    g++ -c main.cpp

DList.o: include/DList.cpp
    g++ -c include/DList.cpp

Person.o: include/Person.cpp
    g++ -c include/Person.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o
```

I don't know what should I do although I read some about these errors on the net.

// EDIT
I changed Object.cpp and Object.h to Person.cpp and Person.h, moved *.cpp files to main directory and changed #include paths in *.cpp files.

Errors:

```
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `main':|
...main.cpp|19|undefined reference to `DListIterator<Person>::go(int)'|
...main.cpp|20|undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& operator<< <Person>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, DList<Person>&)'|
...main.cpp|21|undefined reference to `DList<Person>::~DList()'|
...main.cpp|21|undefined reference to `DList<Person>::~DList()'|
obj/Debug/main.o||In function `DList<Person>::insert(Person&)':|
...include/DList.h|45|undefined reference to `DList<Person>::insert(Person&, DListIterator<Person>&)'|
||=== Build finished: 5 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

It makes no difference if I build starting make in command line or using Build function in Code::Blocks.

When I copied all code from *.cpp files to *.h files, compiler returned no errors, so I think that it's only linker problem.

Comment: I think it's a linker order issue. Try `DList.o Object.o main.o`.

Comment: I've tried different cases. In every order there are the same errors.

Comment: Can you post the exact linker error and also in what fashion that function is contained by .h and .cpp files

Comment: 100% confirm that the specific things you are being told are undefined are in fact in one of the `.cpp` files corresponding to one of the `.o` files you are linking.

Comment: Why are your source files in your include directory?

Comment: Can you cut and paste the full compilation steps attempted & errors after a "make clean"?  Are all the .o files there in the directory?  Can you run the final `g++ main.o DList.o Object.o -o project` from the shell / command prompt without error?  If not, you may have some subtle error in namespaces or arguments meaning the definitions/implementations don't match the declarations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are attempting to separately compile a template. This is not possible in general, as a template will only be instantiated when it is used, and it is never used in the `DList.cpp` file. Try one of two things:

- Move the definitions of the functions in `DList` into the header file (this is the normal way of doing things).
- Put some explicit instantiations of `DList` in to the `DList.cpp` file. (Example: `template class DList<Person>;`)

Full example of the problem: Currently you have:

```
//DList.h
template<typename T>
class DList {
    void insert(T& newPerson);
    //etc
};

//DList.cpp
#include "DList.h"
//The when this is being compiled, 
//the compiler does not know about Person,
//so it cannot instantiate this function.
template<typename T>
void DList<T>::insert(T& newPerson) {
    //implementation
}
//etc

//main.cpp
#include "DList.h"
#include "Person.h"
int main() {
    //When this is being compiled, it does not know the
    //definition of the out-of-line functions in `DList`,
    //so it cannot instantiate them.
    DList<Person> people;
    people.insert(Person("Joe"));
}
```

One possible fix is to remove `DList.cpp` and put the definitions in "DList.hpp":

```
//DList.hpp
template<typename T>
class DList {
    void insert(T& newPerson) {
        //implementation
    }
    ~DList();
    //etc
};
//the implementations can alternatively be
//placed outside the class, but in the header:
template<typename T>
DList<T>::~DList() {
    //implementation
}
```

The other fix is to explicitly instantiate `DList` (in a compilation unit where the definitions are available):

```
//DList.cpp
#include "DList.h"
#include "Person.h"
template<typename T>
void DList<T>::insert(T& newPerson) {
    //implementation
}
//Explicit instantiation:
template class DList<Person>;
```

Comment: First of your suggestions helped. The second not, but it's ok. Is any case in which I can put definitions of template's methods into other file (.cpp)?

Comment: Thanks! It seems I had asleeped while was learing about this :)